# Annotation not getting copied to getter and setter

Tags: java, kotlin, reflection, annotations

So, I have this annotation class

```
@Target(AnnotationTarget.PROPERTY_GETTER, AnnotationTarget.PROPERTY_SETTER, AnnotationTarget.PROPERTY)
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
annotation class MyTestAnnotation(val text: String)
```

And I'm using this like this

```
interface MyTestInterface {

    @MyTestAnnotation("temp")
    var tempString: String
}
```

This is how I'm instantiating my interface using reflection.

```
fun <T> with(myInterface: Class<T>): T {
    return Proxy.newProxyInstance(
        myInterface.classLoader,
        arrayOf<Class<*>>(myInterface),
        invocationHandler
    ) as T
}

private val invocationHandler = InvocationHandler { _, method, args ->
    Log.e("Called method:", method.name) // setTempString
    Log.e("declaredAnnotations", method.declaredAnnotations.size.toString()) // 0
    Log.e("annotations", method.annotations.size.toString()) // 0
    Log.e("args", args.size.toString()) // 1
}
```

I'm calling it like this

```
val myInterface = with(MyTestInterface::class.java)
myInterface.tempString = "123"
```

I'm not able to access the member `text` of the annotation class because in my `invocationHandler` I'm not getting the annotation(as you can see both the arrays are of length zero).

My question: Is there any way I can copy the annotation to the getter and setter so I can get access to the data which I put in the annotation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the use-site target of the annotation. For example, if you want to annotate both the setter and the getter you can do:

```
@set:YourAnnotation
@get:YourAnnotation
val aProperty: AType
```

Official documentation: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/annotations.html#annotation-use-site-targets

Comment: Oh yeah!! Thanks, man! Do we have any other way?

Comment: You could try using Kotlin reflection instead of (or in addition to) Java reflection. E.g. this `println(MyTestInterface::tempString.annotations)` prints `[@MyTestAnnotation(text="temp")]` without the need for `get` and `set`. But I'm not familiar with it